# how to detect if process is being debugged

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, detect

I have a C++ application, lets call *dummy1*, which I want to debug in cgdb, a curl interface to gdb, in Linux (ubuntu 12.04).
The debugging needs to be synchronized with a controller process, which I have the source of.

**edit** the controller connects and communicate with and control dummy1 via http. I want to break dummy1 in a certain function and step as I like. When this happens, I would like get controller notified. Then controller should change its state, until it gets notified that I continued dummy1. Meanwhile it should not try to control, or initiate communication with, dummy1.

My problem is how do I detect in / notify *controller*  that/if my *dummy1* process is currently being debugged (in a break)?

Comment: You're over thinking it, just add a command line flag and pass it to your app when you start it in the debugger.

Comment: @naxa If this is on x86 you could try and hook INT1 and INT3.  That is one technique that some software will use to somewhat prevent debugging.

Comment: i once handled a similar problem by having my dummy process fork-exec a gdb instance, sending the pid as part of the command line. In fact, I actually did it using an `xterm` front end with a foreign ip for the display so I could debug it remotely. Something like that (maybe not *that* nuts, but perhaps the first part) may work for you.

Answer (score 5):

There are several possible solutions:

- Direct answer to your question: your controller could read /proc/PID/status (where PID is that of the `dummy1` process), and look at `TracerPid` field. If non-zero, `dummy1` is being debugged, and controller should abstain from trying to control.

Note that this answers "is dummy1 being debugged", not whether dummy1 is currently stopped. In order to allow controller to control again, you would have to detach GDB from dummy1.

- A possibly better approach is to attach GDB to *both* dummy1 *and* controller. Then you can stop the controller at any point you wish, step through dummy1, resume either or both, etc. etc.

Newer versions of GDB support debugging multiple processes at once. However, you might find this quite confusing.

- Another alternative is to simply run two instances of GDB -- one to control the controller, and another to control dummy1.